# Public and Private key encryption in simple math

Tags: encryption, reference-request

Can anybody show me (or point me to resource) how to generate public key and private key with simple math? Steps which can be reproduced in a simple calculator – so the message, keys  all can be numbers for test. The values can be simple; it’s fine if it’s hackable. And how will you go about encrypting and decrypting the message with keys?

Let me know if you don't understand my question.

Comment: RSA algorithm is explained pretty well at [RSA Algorithm](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html). It contains both example with small numbers (suitable for calculator) and large numbers. Even with simple numbers it's more convenient if you have advanced calculator as operations common in discrete mathematics are not found on simple calculators. However, RSA with insecurely small numbers is possible to calculate using mental arithmetic.

Comment: See also Koblitz's "Kid RSA" (Example 3 [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~koblitz/crlogia.html)).